# How do I read "signed_in" cookie from root domain when on subdomain?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

It's an online school.
If a user is signed in to the school, the domain "justudy.co.il" will have a cookie of "signed_in" with the value 'true'.

```
$.cookie("signed_in") returns 'true'
```

if he is signed out

```
$.cookie("signed_in") returns 'null'
```

I want to check if the cookie "signed_in" on the rootdomain "justudy.co.il" is true, using javascript on the page "forum.justudy.co.il".
Something like

```
    $.get('justudy.co.il').cookie("signed_in") that will return 'true' or 'null'
```

that is a made up code obviously.

is that possible? and if so, how?
the forum is one platform (forum platform) while the school is on a different platform (school platform)

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Cookies from a parent domain are automatically inherited by subdomains. You don't have to do anything special.

Comment: Unless the subdomain sets its own cookie with the same name, then it shadows the parent domain.

Comment: I don't seem to find that cookie on the subdomain.

Comment: When you have the subdomain page loaded, do you see the cookie in Developer Tools?

Comment: No :( I even tried to set a new cookie on my root domain writing $.cookie("justudySignedIn", 'true'), but when I load forum.justudy.co.il and type $.cookie("justudySignedIn"); in the console, it says there isn't such a cookie.

Comment: Cookies can also be associated with a directory name, they won't be visible outside that folder.